# Usings variables AND regex within substitute routine in AWK?

Tags: regex, awk

Let's say I have an AWK script, where the string variable `my_var` is defined (and equals to `;` -- just in case this matters). Now, I want to delete one or more occurrences of `my_var` from another string:

```
gsub(/my_var+/, "", another_string)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. But how should I construct this `gsub` command (or, how should I escape `my_var`) to make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct regex using string:

```
gsub(my_var "+", "", another_string)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will accept this as an answer as soon as SO will allow me :).